# AutoMapper project nested objects where inner object is nullable failing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I am using AutoMapper to project the following structure

```
public class OuterSource
{
    ....
    public Guid? InnerId { get; set }
    public InnerSource Inner { get; set; }
}

public class InnerSource
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class OuterDest
{
    ....
    public InnerDest Inner { get; set; }
}

public class InnerDest
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}


var result = AutoMapper.Project<OuterSource, OuterDest>(query);
```

As you can see, the Inner object is nullable.

The projection works fine if the Inner object has a value, but if the Inner object is null, EF will throw an Exception as if it does not understand that the InnerDest should in fact be null.

```
"The cast to value type 'Guid' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."
```

Using

```
var result = AutoMapper.Map<IEnumerable<OuterSource>, IEnumerable<OuterDest>>(query);
```

does solve my problem, but clearly I would prefer to use project.

Is there any good way around this, or can I simply not use .Project for nested mappings with nullable inner objects?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your source object has nullable fields and your destination object doesn't. If a property  is not nullable and you try and set it to null you will get an exception. To fix it you have 2 options. Either make the fields in the destination nullable

```
public class OuterDest
{
     public Guid? Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Or create a custom handler in you mapping to handle nulls and set default values for the fields in question.

Answer (score 0):

What is your mapping config? You need to individually map both the outsource => outerdest and the innersource => innerdest in order for mapping to be understood.